# session events dont work in spring session

Tags: java, spring, session, tomcat, spring-session

My app uses http and stomp over WebSocket. So i need to refresh my httpSession when user uses WebSockets So to not invent bicycles i decided to use Spring Session, as this provides clear integration between Http and WebSockets. But i was faced with a problem. When i used TOMCAT SESSION implementation i had this listener:

```
@Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        servletContext.addListener(new HttpSessionEventPublisher());
...
}
```

And it had worked just perfect. Session registry received a SessionDestroyEvent and destroyed a session.

Now, with Spring Session based on H2, it doesn't work.
I tried different approach like this:

```
@Bean
public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionPublisher() {
    return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
}


@Bean
public HttpSessionListener httpSessionListener() {
    return new HttpSessionListener() {
        @Override
        public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se) {
            System.out.println("I EXIST");
        }

        @Override
        public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
            System.out.println("I EXIST");
        }
    };
}
```

But it doesn't work too.

I use SpringSession with H2 storage, my config is:

```
@EnableJdbcHttpSession(maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds = 15)
public class H2SessionConfig {

    @Bean(name = "session_dataSource")
    public EmbeddedDatabase dataSource() {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
                .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                .addScript("org/springframework/session/jdbc/schema-h2.sql").build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(@Qualifier("session_dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {
        return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpSessionListener httpSessionListener() {
        return new HttpSessionListener() {
            @Override
            public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se) {
                System.out.println("I EXIST");
            }

            @Override
            public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
                System.out.println("I EXIST");
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionPublisher() {
        return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Spring Session JDBC does not support publishing of session events due to obvious limitations of a RDBMS in that regard.

This limitation is documented both in [reference manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/#api-jdbcoperationssessionrepository) and [`JdbcOperationsSessionRepository` javadoc](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/master/spring-session/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/jdbc/JdbcOperationsSessionRepository.java#L65-L67).

Comment: Please clarify why its so obvious that it doesn't support these events... The db is not expiring the sessions. That is done in the java code and rhe java code could fire the event and also manage the listeners for that matter.

Comment: The event needs to be propagated to all the cluster members. In order to achieve that, you need some sort of pub-sub mechanism. A relational database is limited in that regard compared to a data store like Redis or Hazelcast.

Comment: I'm not convinced that is so mandatory. As long as one cluster member receives the event that is acceptable. I would guess that in some use cases each cluster member might like the event but for a lot of use cases as long as 1 cluster member processes the event that is sufficient.

Comment: The goal of Spring Session's HttpSession event support has always been to support propagation of events to all cluster members. Without pub-sub mechanism that's not possible. We also wouldn't want to have a situation where a feature fundamentally behaves different from one data store to another, so if we cannot ensure that the choice is simply to not support events.
Sidenote: Ideal session data store should be capable of expiring sessions with TTL based mechanism, and inform application about that via pub-sub. The fact that some SessionRepository handle expiry is more of a workaround.